# Unable to install build-essential for Ubuntu-20.04

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

When build-essential is installed, it shows unmet dependencies

```
    sudo apt install build-essential 

    Reading package lists... 

    Done Building dependency tree

    Reading state information... 

    Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested         
    an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some                       required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
    build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:9.2) but it is not installable 
                      Depends: g++ (>= 4:9.2) but it is not installable 
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When searched for 'apt-cache policy g++'

The output shows :

```
    g++: Installed: (none) 
    Candidate: (none) 
    Version table:
```

A similar output is shown when searched for 'apt-cache policy gcc'.
The output is

```
    gcc: Installed: (none) 
    Candidate: (none) 
    Version table:
```

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository universe`  https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: ? What's the reply from the command `sudo apt install gcc`